# Server side java for handling Ajax request

Tags: java, ajax

I'm a javascript webapp programmer, know java SE but not much of java web development.

When I do js development, I write codes like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://domain/abc.xml",
}).done(function ( data ) {
   //todo
}
});
```

taking it granted that HTTP server will handle my Ajax request without any of my effort.

But now I have some js codes with Ajax requests, and I have to map the resources name on the server side. For example, when I request abc.xml, the server should respond with def.xml, mapping abc.xml -> def.xml.

So I guess I should write a servlet (have to use java) on the server side, override methods like doGet(). Any example to start with?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic of ajax is all client-side.  As far as the server is concerned, you are requesting the main page, and then some time later you're requesting `http://domain/abc.xml`.

The server doesn't need to understand that the request has anything to do with ajax.  Any simple servlet example will suffice.

Comment: This is covered in the possible duplicate question.